# assert_frame_equal is returning an error even though both the dataframes are identical in terms of data, column datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes (DF1 and DF2), one created from sqllite select query (DF1) and another one from directly from the csv (DF2). The data in the sqllite table is inserted from the same csv that is used while reading it directly.

Some of the column names dtype were different so I changed the dtypes of the columns in DF2 as well.

e.g. task6_my['year'] = task6_my['year'].astype('int64') since dtype of engines column in the sqllite table is int whereas it was float64. This way I have done it for all the columns whereever there was a mismatch.(I am checking it through task6_sql.dtypes, task6_my.dtypes and it tells me which columns have a different dtypes.)

Once I pass the DF1, DF2 in assert_frame_equal it throws an exception:

AssertionError: DataFrame.iloc[:, 5] (column name="engines") are different

DataFrame.iloc[:, 5] (column name="engines") values are different (100.0 %)
[index]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
[left]:  [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[right]: [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

In the engines column of both the DFs, indexes, column_names and even the values are identical. I have even tried setting check_dtype = False, check_names = False along with atol = 0.001 or rtol=1e-5. But none seems to be working.

Comment: What return `print (DF1[DF1.ne(DF2).any(axis=1)])` ?

Comment: I figured out? What I did is instead of changing the dtype of Df2 columns, I changed the data type of DF1 columns.